# DateTime not working: See if date is older than 30 days

Tags: php, datetime

For some reason that I'm not fully aware of, this isn't working. I want to prevent certain things if the date of a published article is older than 30 days, where `fetchData["article_date"]` in the database is `2015-09-08 15:18:27`

```
 $new = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
 $old = new DateTime($fetchData["article_date"]);
 if(strtotime($old->modify('+30 days') < $new)) { 

    // Older than 30 days

  }
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, `$old->modify('+30 days') < $new` returns a boolean, how do you `strtotime` a boolean? Just remove `strtotime`

Comment: Why are you playing pick-a-mix with DateTime objects and standard unix timestamp date functions.... use DateTime diff() to find the difference between the two DateTime objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if the date of a published article is older than 30 days, you can do something like this:

```
$new = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$old = new DateTime($fetchData["article_date"]);
if($old->modify('+30 days')->getTimestamp() < $new->getTimestamp()) { 
    // older than 30 days
}
```

Comment: @P.Nick You're welcome. Please *accept* the answer it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just an example

```
$new = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$old = new DateTime('2015-12-22 15:18:27');
$interval = $old->diff($new);

if($interval->format('%a') > 30) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is wrong

the `modify` function produces an object and you can directly compare it with your `$new` which is an object as well.

```
$new = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$old = new DateTime($fetchData["article_date"]);


 if($old->modify('+30 days') < $new) { 

    echo "hello";

  }
```